# Getting CPUID Into in 64 bit assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpuid

So, I'm trying to pull info from the CPUID function. For now, I just want the stepping info, which should be contained in the first 3 bits in %rax after calling cpuid. However, when I get the data, then bitwise and it with 7, I get a segfault. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#   CPUID
#       Command stored in %RAX
#       0. Vendor ID string & max CPUID option value supported
#           %RBX contains low 4 bytes of string
#           %RDX contains middle 4 bytes of string
#           %RCX contains last 4 bytes of string
#       1. Processor type, family, model, and stepping info
#       2. Processor cache config
#       3. Processor serial number
#       4. Cache config (# threads, # cores, physical properties)
#       5. Monitor info
#       80000000h. Extended vendor ID string & supported levels.
#       80000001h. Extended 1.
#       8000000(2-4)h. Extended processor name string

.section .data
    #asciz null-terminates the string
    out7: .asciz "stepping_id: %x\n"

.section .bss
    .lcomm buffer, 4

.section .text
.global _start
_start:
    # stack stuff
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    # vendor ID value into rax
    movq $1, %rax
    cpuid

    movq $buffer, %rsi

    # Using rcx as a temp register
    movq %rax, %rcx
    andq 7,%rcx;
    movq %rcx, (%rsi)

    movq $0, %rax

    movq $out7, %rdi

    call printf

    #exit
    movq $0, %rdi
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: Looking back at it, maybe i'm incorrectly using the buffer?

Comment: You are missing a `$` for the immediate. It should be `andq $7,%rcx` as `andq 7, %rcx` is trying to access memory at address `7`.

Comment: Omg thank you @Jester I knew it would be some dumb typo that i just kept missing

Comment: yeah the immediate value thing didn't make sense to me at first...

Comment: After you fix that, you’ll find that your printf prints the address of buffer, rather than the value you want.

Comment: CPUID takes 32 bit parameters and returns 32 bit values. You can use eax and ecx.